# How to detect end of HTTP response body for Content-Length differ body size?

Tags: http

How to detect end of HTTP response body for Content-Length differ body size?
Http 1.1

I want to implement a http proxy.
In normal, http proxy receive a response from server; if header has Content-Length L1, I think the length of body is L1.
But, if Content-Length differ body size, how to detect end of body?
(In keep-alive mode, I can't received eof.)

As mention in RFC2616 section4.4
"HTTP/1.1 user agents MUST notify the user when an invalid length is received and detected."

Answer (score 0):

a) RFC 2616 is very outdated

b) the answer should be over here: http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#message.body.length

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I red the above section, But I can't find solving method.
In my case, as a http proxy, I need find "Content-Length value is incorrect" case, then I can told the client.  
In http 1.1, keep-alive, I can't distinguish the buffer is current response overflow data or next new response data.

Comment: There is no such thing as "incorrect", spec-wise. If a content length is specified, it's authoritative, so that's the number of bytes to read and forward. If there are less bytes to be read, the message is truncated.